# Firestore: multiple where()'s and orderBy()

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im making a flutter app, and in it I have posts called 'waves'. Id like to get them posted by a certain id, excluding blockedIds, and sorted by the time createdAt. When I try, I am getting the following error:

> 'conditionField == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([createdAt]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([senderId])" when an inequality operator is invoked.

Which is coming from the following code:

```
initial = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('waves')
          .where('replyTo', isEqualTo: waveId);
      initial = initial.where('senderId', whereNotIn: blockerUserIds);
      initial = initial.orderBy('createdAt', descending: true);
      initial = initial.limit(5);
      query = await initial.get();
```

The suggestions I have read so far seem to suggest that breaking the query up into multiple statements like this, but i still seem to be getting this error. Anyone have an idea whats going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, in order to have a `whereNotIn` condition in you query you need to make sure that the first `orderBy` on that query is on the same field as that condition.

So:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('waves')
  .where('replyTo', isEqualTo: waveId)
  .orderBy('senderId')
  .where('senderId', whereNotIn: blockerUserIds)
  .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
  .limit(5);
```

*Note: this query likely required a composite index, so be sure to check the error output for a message about that and a link to where to most easily create that.*

This also implies that the results will first be ordered on the value of `senderId` and only on `createdAt` for documents that have the same `senderId`. If that is not what you want, you'll have to re-order the documents in your application code after retrieving them.

Comment: I see, so is it not possible to structure a query in this way? What seems to happen here is that 5 posts are queried, then paginated to get more. In the case of this solution, there would situations where the initial posts could be older than the future paginated queries. My ideal situation would be that the queried documents would always be coming back in the order of createdAt. Is that not possible?

Comment: The problem is that you can only have one so-called relational operation in Firestore, and both `.orderBy('senderId')` and `.orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)` compete for that.  If you'd like to learn more about why that is, have a look at Todd's excellent video on [queries in Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=2).